# A few questions about Metro style applications

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a few questions about Metro style applications.

1. Do they require .NET Framework or any framework?
2. Which programming languages can be used to create Metro style apps?
3. Can they be cross platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It does not require using .NET - you can build native apps with C++ or C++/CX or use HTML and Javascript
2. C#, Visual Basic, C++, C++/CX, XAML, Javascript, HTML, CSS
3. It depends what you understand by cross platform - these apps can run on any Windows 8 platform, but not on Windows Phone, Mac or Linux

Answer (score 0):

Metro applications are either developed using Microsoft .Net (c#) OR C++ OR HTML 5 / Javascript

[Api Reference of Metro Aplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br211369)

For more detailed information, check this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/

---

**HTML5 - Javascript**
These are the languages used by any browser, making them compatible on any system

**Microsoft .Net**
Can only be run on a Windows computer, but you may want to check [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) for compiling multi-platform applications made in C#

**C++**
Well C++ is c++... it can pretty much do anything anywhere

Comment: Microsoft does not really recommend HTML5 over the other languages unless I missed something - they usually say to use what you know or what you need to implement your features (e.g. C++ with DirectX for games). C++ is not .NET.

Comment: Thank you replay. So i have VIsual studio 2012 RC how i can build metro style application? I cannot find it in new project window

Comment: user525717: Make sure you have Windows 8 installed and running when you open VS 2012 RC.